# Specify Python version-specific testenv settings, when platform is used

Tags: python, tox

How can I set a testenv that specifies settings for a specific Python version? As a minimal example,

```
[tox]
envlist = py{36,37,38,39}-{mylinux,macos,mywindows}
skipsdist = True

[testenv]
platform = mylinux: linux
           mymacos: darwin
           mywindows: win32
setenv =
    mylinux: PLATFORM = linux
    mymacos: PLATFORM = macos
    mywindows: PLATFORM = windows

commands =
    {envpython} -c "print('{env:PLATFORM}')"  # This env is used in setup.py
    # other commands

[testenv:py36]
deps =
    pydantic  # No dataclasses until py37
```

If I run `tox -e py36-mylinux`, `pydantic` won't be installed. If I run `tox -e py36`, it would say

```
ERROR:   py36: unresolvable substitution(s):
    commands: 'PLATFORM'
Environment variables are missing or defined recursively.
```

How can I specify testenv settings for a particular Python version, without having to specify all other info in environment names (especially when the envlist gets long)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way; put this in `[testenv]` (and remove `[testenv:py36]`):

```
deps =
    py36: pydantic  # No dataclasses until py37
```

Verify config with `tox --showconfig`

PS. `tox` doesn't combine environments; once you have a separate `[testenv:py36]` it will not be combined with `mylinux`.

Comment: Would `py36-mylinux: pydantic` work for the combination? Could you point me to the reference?

Comment: 1. I just tried and yes — it limits `deps` to just one environment. 2. https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#complex-factor-conditions